# Launching a certain app with 'extra' parameters?

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

I have a screenshot that I would like my users to be able to share on their social media accounts with some text that I assign.

My function takes the name of which social media app to look for, once it's found I populate the intent parameters and run a chooser object with 'Select'.

The problem is it doesn't launch the app right away. It still shows that 'Share' screen to choose the app from, so I have to explicitly tap on the app to launch it.

Here's my code:

```
    static bool ShareScreenshot_Android_ToSpecific(string ScreenshotPath, string SocialNetwork)
    {
        bool FoundApp = false;

        AndroidJavaClass Unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject CurrentActivity = Unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        AndroidJavaClass IntentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaClass PackageManagerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");

        AndroidJavaObject IntentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

        IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", IntentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
        IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/jpeg");

        AndroidJavaObject PackageManager = CurrentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

        AndroidJavaObject Apps = PackageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>(
            "queryIntentActivities", IntentObject, 0);

        int Count = Apps.Call<int>("size");

        //Debug.Log("[Social Share] Activity count: " + Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            var App = Apps.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("get", i);

            var ActivityInfo = App.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("activityInfo");
            var PackageName = ActivityInfo.Get<string>("packageName");
            var ActivityName = ActivityInfo.Get<string>("name");

            if (ActivityName.ToLower().Contains(SocialNetwork) || 
                PackageName.ToLower().Contains(SocialNetwork))
            {
                Debug.Log("[Social Share] Found app: " + PackageName);
                Debug.Log("[Social Share] Found app: " + ActivityName);

                AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
                AndroidJavaObject UriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", 
                    "file://" + ScreenshotPath);

                IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra",
                    IntentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), ScreenshotText);

                IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra",
                    IntentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), UriObject);

                IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setPackage", PackageName);

                FoundApp = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (FoundApp)
        {
            AndroidJavaObject chooser = IntentClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("createChooser", IntentObject, "Select");
            CurrentActivity.Call("startActivity", chooser);
        }

        return (FoundApp);
    }
```

Here's how I call it:

```
ShareScreenshot_Android_ToSpecific(ScreenshotPath, "twi"); // or "face", etc
```

I want to launch the app once it's found with those extra text and stream values.

I tried:

```
IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addCategory",
         IntentClass.GetStatic<string>("CATEGORY_LAUNCHER"));

IntentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags",
         IntentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"));
```

But it didn't do anything. Do I need another intent? or how does this actually work?

PS: My first time interacting with Android API.

Comment: what do you exactly want. Want to open particular social media app through intent ?

Comment: I want to launch a certain social media app with the EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_STREAM values

Comment: i think you can go with setpackage parameters through intent.?